# Is there a solution where I don't have to fine tune my margins and paddings on my onepager?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I had a problem where the buttons didn't scroll me to the top of the anchor and would instead scroll into the section (that was because my navbar is fixed and is overlapping the section).

I fixed it with a few margins and paddings but I feel like there is a much better and more simple solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/2n9b0ohp/76/

I experimented around for a few hours but couldn't really find the perfect solution, there was always something wrong and not working.

```
$(function() {
  var shrinkHeader = 100;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
    if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });

  function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
});
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

  var navTop = $('#navbar').offset().top;
  var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
  var windowH = $(window).height();

  $('.section').height(windowH);

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    //for the nav bar:
    if (st > navTop) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': navHeight
      }); //fix  scrolling issue due to the fix nav bar
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('fix');
      $('.section:eq(0)').css({
        'margin-top': '0'
      });
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
      if (st + navHeight > $(this).offset().top && st + navHeight <= $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        // or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
        //or $('#nav li:eq('+index+')').removeClass('active');
      }

    });

  });

});



//
```

```
/* MAIN */

/* SECTION HOME */
#home {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -128px;
  padding-top: 128px;
}

#homebild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION WIR-UEBER-UNS */
#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  top: -208px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#wir-ueber-unsbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION AKTIONEN */
#aktionen {
  height: 853px !important;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -288px;
  z-index: -3;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#aktionenbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION TERMINVEREINBARUNG */
#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 853px !important;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -368px;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -4;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

#terminvereinbarungbild {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 853px;
}

/* SECTION INFOS */
#infos {
  height: 772px !important;
  width: 1280px;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 80px;
  top: -448px;
  z-index: -5;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

/* MAIN ENDE */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>OptikTack</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="body">
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <nav id="navbar">
          <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
          <a href="#home" id="logo"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/przxCGcx/Logo.png" class="logo"></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#wir-ueber-uns">Wir über uns</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#aktionen">Aktionen</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#terminvereinbarung">Terminvereinbarung</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-sweep-to-top"><a href="#infos">Infos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- NAVIGATION ENDE -->
        <!-- MAIN -->
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <!-- home section -->
        <section id="home" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tgk5cWmx/Bild-1.jpg" alt="Frau" id="homebild" width="1280px">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- home section ende -->
        <!-- wir-ueber-uns section -->
        <section id="wir-ueber-uns" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/FH6RSxbF/Bild-2.jpg" width="1280px" id="wir-ueber-unsbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- wir-ueber-uns section ende -->
        <!-- aktionen section -->
        <div id="reference"></div>
        <section id="aktionen" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/k5P0L6qF/Bild-5.jpg" width="1280px" id="aktionenbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- aktionen section ende -->
        <!-- terminvereinbarung section -->
        <section id="terminvereinbarung" class="section">
          <div>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6q8b8tBp/Bild-9.jpg" width="1280px" id="terminverinbarungbild">
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- terminvereinbarung section ende -->
        <!-- infos section -->
        <section id="infos" class="section">
          <div>
            <p>section 5</p>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- infos section ende -->
        <!-- MAIN ENDE -->
```

Comment: Hmm... instead of providing all of your code, can you please cut it down to the sections you think are causing the issue? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and re-edit your question, thanks!

Comment: Also, why put your code in a fiddle when there are stack snippets?

Comment: I tried to put it into a snippet but there was an error which I didn't know how to fix. I'm new to this sorry

Comment: I edited the code now, hope it's enough :)

Answer (score 0):

as it is only problematic for the first section, why not just scroll to the total top when clicking home?

```
$("a[href='#home']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Do I delete the margins and paddings then too?

Comment: you should give it a try

Comment: This worked for **home** and **Wir über uns** but not for the rest of them.